# Change value to undefined mongoose findOneAndUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update a schema values based on user input.

My schema is:

```
({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  color: {
    type: String,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

The `name` field is required however the `color` field is optional. So, supposing the user created a document:

```
{
    "name": "Blue",
    "color": "#20387d"
}
```

he can then edit the same document where he doesn't provide the `color` value:

```
 {
     "name": "Blue"
 }
```

My code for update is:

```
  const { name, color} = req.body;
  const document = await Model.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
      _id: req.params.id,
    },
    { $set: { name, color }},
    { new: true }
  );
```

This should update `color` value to `undefined` in my MongoDB. However, the `color` remains same as provided initially whereas the `name` updates.
I want the `color` to change to `undefined` if its not provided by the user. How do I do that?

Comment: what happens when you pass ```{ $set: { name, color: undefined }``` in query, does it works now  ?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't :(

Comment: if you really want to remove it, you have to use [`$unset`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/). But I prefer using `null`  as value instead of `undefined`.

Comment: But to `$unset` the value, I will have to first check if the `color` value exists or not. 
I thought there would be a way to do it directly with `findOneAndUpdate` function

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want use $unset or setting that value to something else, that leaves only one way.

Use `findById`/`findOne` to fetch that Doc then modify its content then save it.

```js
  const document = await Model.findById(
    req.params.id,
    { name: 1, color: 1 }
  );
  //..
  document.color = req.body.color || undefined
  //..
  await document.save()
```

above code works because mongoose detects change.

Answer (score 0):

As @bogdanoff indicated in the comments, you can set the value to `null`, not `undefined`.